# Convergence in distribution of random sequence plus sequence of numbers

Tags: convergence, slutsky-theorem

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables and $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers.
Slutsky's Theorem says that if $Y_n$ is another random sequence and $Y_n\overset{d}{\to} Y, X_n\overset{d}{\to}X$, then
$$X_n+Y_n\overset{d}{\to} X+Y.$$

What happens for $$X_n+a_n\overset{d}{\to} \ ?$$ if $a_n\to a$ as $n\to\infty$?
Can you explain me?

Comment: You can identify $a_n$ with the atom at $a_n.$ Convergence of the $a_n$ is equivalent to convergence of these atoms in distribution.  However, your statement of the theorem is not the standard one (and indeed is not true), where at least one of the $X_n$ or $Y_n$ sequences must converge in *probability* to a constant.

Comment: @whuber Could you provide some insight in this "identifying a sequence of real numbers with the atom"? For example, if I were to use this identification in a proof, how can I prove that convergence of the $a_n$ is equivalent to convergence of these atoms in distribution? Also, does this mean that I can basically treat $a_n$ like a random variable that converges in distribution?

Comment: @psyph The identification associates any standard real number $a$ with the distribution function $\mathcal{I}_{[a,\infty)}$ (the indicator function of the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\ge a\}$). The rest is a straightforward application of the two definitions of convergence (of sequences of real numbers and sequences of random variables).

Comment: @whuber Thanks a lot for that formal definition. What I was still wondering about, does this mean that I can include $a_n$ in a probabilistic statement, say for example $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(|a_n-a|>\epsilon)$? Intuitively, it seems clear that this statement would go to zero as n goes to infinity, but then again I'm wondering where the probabilistic element would be in a predefined sequence.

Comment: @psyph That statement makes mathematical sense provided at least one of $a$ and $a_n$ is interpreted as a random variable.  In the extreme case where $(a_n)$ is a sequence of numbers and $a$ is a number, that probability equals $0$ when $|a_n-a|\le\epsilon$ and otherwise is $1.$ That sequence of probabilities has a limit iff eventually they are all $1$ or all $0:$ that is, eventually either all $a_n$ are within $\epsilon$ of $a$ or eventually they are all further than $\epsilon$ from $a,$ respectively.